# How to add gradient color in card?

Tags: flutter, colors, card

How to add gradient color in the background of a card ? Should I reproduce this card with a container and a box decoration or is there another simple way ?

Comment: Can you add your code snippet. It can be done by using container

Comment: Check this out :  https://betterprogramming.pub/instagram-gradient-animation-for-flutter-1d74d3869997

Answer (score 21):

Try below code hope it help to you in below answer change Color your need.

```
         Card(
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Colors.yellow,
                    Colors.orangeAccent,
                    Colors.yellow.shade300,
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(), //declare your widget here
            ),
          ),
```

Your Card look like-> [image]

If you are gradient background to card or gradient border to card try below code

```
  Container(
        
          height: 50,
          width: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.yellow,
                Colors.orangeAccent,
                Colors.yellow.shade300,
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
          ),
        child:Card(
          color:Colors.white,
          child: Container(), //declare your widget here
        ),
      ),
```

Your Screen like -> [image]

Comment: Thx but it does not fit the border of the card :(

Comment: Thx but it does not fit the border of the card :(

Comment: Refer my updated answer, one thing forgot black color of updated image try updated code hope it's helpful to you

Comment: Thank you but it still does not fit the border radius of the card.

Comment: can you tell me the what do you want in image or picture?

Comment: I do not need an image or a picture, but a gradient color.

Comment: Are you Try my answer?

Comment: Add `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias` to your `Card` widget if you want the gradient to be clipped to the card shape (by default it will spill outside of the card rounded edges)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but you can try this to achieve a card gradient with border radius

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black38,
        blurRadius: 3.0,
        spreadRadius: 0.0,
        offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
      )
    ],
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [startColor, endColor],
      begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      end: Alignment.topRight,
    ),
  ),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 6),
        TextWidget(
          title,
          typographyToken: TypographyToken.text14SemiBold,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        TextWidget(
          "$pendingCount Pending Request",
          typographyToken: TypographyToken.text10,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 6),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Result :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr81q.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample that I tried just now. Works fine for me.

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Colors.black, Colors.white],
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight)),
          )
```

Comment: Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: Thx, this is the best alternative I had, but you must also add circle border and an InkWell widget to do it like a card. I will do this if there is no other solution..

Answer (score 0):

Another way and probably the best in my opinion:

```
  Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                    end: Alignment.center,
                    colors: [Colors.deepOrangeAccent, Colors.orange],
                  ),
                ),
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
```

Output:

[Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSoxe.png)

Answer (score -2):

```
Card(
        shadowColor: tabColorAmber,
        elevation: 10,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                Colors.orangeAccent,
                Colors.orangeAccent,
                Colors.yellow.shade100,
              ])),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 140,
        ),
      ),
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXEBP.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).