# Adding Shadow To Semi Transparent Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-container

I am trying to add shadow to my semi-transparent container in flutter but as you might guess shadow can be seen through the container and I cannot achieve what I want.

[image]

I tried nearly all solutions suggested at StackOverflow or Google but they didn't work out.

My current code is below:

```
                         Container(
                            height: 75,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: const [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black26,
                                      offset: Offset(2, 4),
                                      blurStyle: BlurStyle.normal,
                                      blurRadius: 5,
                                      spreadRadius: 2)
                                ],
                                color: kDarkPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Text("ABC"),
                            ),
                          )
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I also tried `BlurStyle.outer` and the other options but it didn't work out.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[How to get shadow outside of a container in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71613843/how-to-get-shadow-outside-of-a-container-in-flutter)

Check out that post, they used linear gradient to try and achieve the result you are wanting.

Comment: It might be but unfortunately, it is not. Transparency changes everything. Thank you anyway.

Comment: have you tried to just match the color that would be there instead of setting it to transparent? it would give a bit of a different look obiously but maybe worth a try, or setting borders with varying thinknesses per side?

Comment: But the background is dynamic so setting just the same color doesn't help. I can feel this can be achieved with some paint method override or clipping but I am very new at flutter so I am stuck.

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end? I am compiling for web (rendered as HTML) and am still unable to achieve the effect of a drop shadow under a transparent card (with 0 elevation and radius)