# Container gradient width in decoration flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, width, gradient

I am having a **Container** that has a `gradient` **BoxDecoration**. What i would like to achieve is to reduce the `width` of the `gradient` just like in `border` so that it can a small thin line. Below is my **Container** code

```
Container(
              width: 220,
              height: 120,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      colors: [
                    Colors.purple.shade900,
                    Colors.purple.shade100,
                  ])),
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text('Linear Gradient'),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: Can you include an image that are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you, I think you increase width and height of second container. refer my same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68856967/13997210)

```
Container(
    width: 220,
    height: 120,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: Alignment.centerRight,
        colors: [
          Colors.purple.shade900,
          Colors.purple.shade100,
        ],
      ),
    ),
    child: Container(
      width: 215,
      height: 115,
      color: Colors.white,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: const Text('Linear Gradient'),
    ),
  ),
```

Result screen -> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your gradient is your outer Container.
If you want to reduce the width of the gradient, reduce the width of your container.

```
Container(
              width: 4,
              height: 120,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      colors: [
                    Colors.purple.shade900,
                    Colors.purple.shade100,
                  ])),
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text('Linear Gradient'),
              ),
            )
```

If you want to wrap your gradient container in a bigger container then wrap it with bigger container