# Is there a way to implement a mesh gradient in in a container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gradient

Is it possible to implement a mesh gradient in a container like in CSS?

```
background-color: hsla(0,100%,50%,1);
background-image:
    radial-gradient(at 40% 20%, hsla(28, 100%, 74%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 80% 0%, hsla(189, 100%, 56%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 0% 50%, hsla(355, 100%, 93%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 80% 50%, hsla(340, 100%, 76%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 0% 100%, hsla(22, 100%, 77%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 80% 100%, hsla(242, 100%, 70%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 0% 0%, hsla(343, 100%, 76%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%);
```

[image]

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68856967/13997210) for gradient container or [flutter_gradients](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gradients), [flutter_gradient_colors](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gradient_colors) packages